# Problema creando un boton para añadir foto en Flutter

Tags: flutter

estoy tratando de crear un Widget botón para añadir una foto en Flutter. Quiero que el botón sea genérico, puesto que mi intención es, que cuando lo llame a través de la vista, le pueda pasar por argumento el parámetro perteneciente al modelo de datos donde quiero guardar la foto.

El botón vendría a tener esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde al seleccionar la foto, debería sustituirse lo que se ve en la imagen por la foto en si, ocupando el espacio disponible.

El problema es que tras seleccionar la foto, y comprobar que efectivamente en la variable que la contiene existe información guardada, el contenedor de la foto permanece sin cambios, es decir, como si no hubiera añadido nada.

A continuación os muestro como está hecho.

```
class AddPhotoButton extends StatelessWidget{

  late XFile _pickedFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  late Uint8List image = Uint8List(0);

  AddPhotoButton({Key? key,
    required this.image
  });

  // carga la imagen de la galeria
  Future<void> getImage() async {
    //setState(ViewState.Busy);
    _pickedFile = (await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery))!;
    image = (_pickedFile != null ? await _pickedFile.readAsBytes() : null)!;
    //setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // usa el model de CreateMoment para poder cargar la foto y enviarla
    return GestureDetector(
        // funcionalidad del boton
        onTap: getImage,
        // aspecto del boton
        child:SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 24 * 2,
          child: image.isEmpty
          // si no hay imagen cargada
              ? DottedBorder(
            borderType: BorderType.RRect,
            color: Colors.green,
            strokeWidth: 3,
            radius: const Radius.circular(10),
            // primer elemento longitud y segundo el espacio
            dashPattern: const [6, 6],
            child: const Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          // si hay imagen cargada que las muestre
              : Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: MemoryImage(image),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  }

}
```

Y así es como realizo la llamada al Widget en la vista:

```
 Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: AddPhotoButton(image:model.GoodSilageImg),
                            )
```

Donde "image: model.GoodSilageImg" es la variable perteneciente a mi modelo de datos donde quiero guardar la imagen.

EDIT: Se me olvido comentarlo, pero el modelo de datos donde se guarda la imagen en principio está definido así (por si sirviera de algo)

```
class VisualEvaluationModel extends BaseModel
{
  List<int> list = 'xxx'.codeUnits;
  late Uint8List GoodSilageImg;

  VisualEvaluationModel()
  {
    GoodSilageImg = Uint8List(0);
  }

}
```

EDIT 2: Intentando utilizar un statefull widget, para utilizar el setState y poder reiniciar la vista tengo el siguiente código:

```
class AddPhotoButton extends StatefulWidget{

  late XFile _pickedFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  late Uint8List image = Uint8List(0);

  AddPhotoButton({Key? key,
    required this.image
  });

  // carga la imagen del momento de la galeria
  Future<void> getImage() async {
    //setState(ViewState.Busy);
    _pickedFile = (await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery))!;
    // puede ser que se no seleccione imagen al final
    image = (_pickedFile != null ? await _pickedFile.readAsBytes() : null)!;
    //setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }

  @override  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {

      // usa el model de CreateMoment para poder cargar la foto y enviarla
      return GestureDetector(
        // funcionalidad del boton
        onTap: getImage,
        // aspecto del boton
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width - 24 * 2,
          child: image.isEmpty
          // si no hay imagen cargada
              ? DottedBorder(
            borderType: BorderType.RRect,
            color: Colors.green,
            strokeWidth: 3,
            radius: const Radius.circular(10),
            // primer elemento longitud y segundo el espacio
            dashPattern: const [6, 6],
            child: const Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          // si hay imagen cargada que las muestre
              : Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: MemoryImage(image),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Pero esto me da problemas con el Gesture Detector, que no puede estar dentro de un create state según dice el error. Se que puede ser un fallo muy tonto pero soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: tienes comentado el setState     que permite refrescar el widget

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que no lo puedo utilizar en un stateless widget  y no me deja hacerlo statefull ( o eso creo), soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo muy bien esa parte. He editado la pregunta con como quedaria en statefull widget @diegoveloper

Comment: el stateful está mal creado, solo es eso, cuando lo crees bien ya podrás usar el setState, revisa la documentación aquí:  https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado, efectivamente, como comentó @diegoveloper el Statefull Widget estaba mal creado.

También tiene un plus añadido y es que para pasarle argumentos debemos llamar a

```
this.widget.nombre_argumento
```

El cual se ha tenido que establecer previamente en la clase principal. Os dejo con el ejemplo corregido:

```
class AddPhotoButton extends StatefulWidget {

  late Uint8List image;

   AddPhotoButton(
      {Key? key,
        required this.image,
        }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AddPhotoButtonState createState() => AddPhotoButtonState();
}

class AddPhotoButtonState extends State<AddPhotoButton> {

  late XFile _pickedFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  //late Uint8List image = Uint8List(0);

  // carga la imagen del momento de la galeria
  Future<void> getImage() async {
    setState((){ViewState.Busy;});
    _pickedFile = (await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery))!;
    this.widget.image = (_pickedFile != null ? await _pickedFile.readAsBytes() : null)!;
    setState((){ViewState.Idle;});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // funcionalidad del boton
      onTap: getImage,
      // aspecto del boton
      child:SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 24 * 2,
        child: widget.image.isEmpty
        // si no hay imagen cargada
            ? DottedBorder(
          borderType: BorderType.RRect,
          color: Colors.green,
          strokeWidth: 3,
          radius: const Radius.circular(10),
          // primer elemento longitud y segundo el espacio
          dashPattern: const [6, 6],
          child: const Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.grey,
                size: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
        // si hay imagen cargada que las muestre
            : Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: MemoryImage(widget.image),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```